# Java Math.random() How random is it?

Tags: java, random

I am working on a project that needs to generate two random numbers from a given range (both of them at the same time, one after another) and check if they are equal to each other - if they are, proceed executing other code; if they aren't - generate the numbers again. Now my question is, if we have a range [0;10], and the first randomly generated number turned out to be 5, is the probability of the second number also being 5 as good as any other number? Specifically, does Math.random() have any "defense" against generating same number if it is called twice consecutively? or it "tries" to not generate the same number?

Comment: You can just do a for loop, and generate 60000 random numbers between 1 - 6, and see for yourself. It's pretty evenly distributed. The implementation details, i don't recall right now, but probably on wikipedia. (pseudo random)

Comment: Math.random is fairly good, but it's *not* a high-grade PRNG (I believe it's a simple LCG implementation).

Comment: Apparent patterns are just as likely as random ones. Here are some examples of non random looking ones http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2011/10/randomly-no-so-random.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generating the same number in the range [0,10] twice in succession is a perfectly valid occurrence for any random number generator.  If it took any steps to prevent that it wouldn't be random.

On any invocation, the chances of any individual number being chosen should be 1:11, and each choice should be independent of previous choices, so the chances that in a pair the second number matches the first is 1 in 11.

As to how random `Math.random()` is, it's *pseudo-random*, meaning it uses an algorithm to generate a series of evenly distributed numbers starting with a "seed" value.  It's not suitable for cryptography but quite good for simulations and other non-cryptographic uses.

Comment: "..each choice should be independent of previous choices.." summed it up for me.

Comment: Thank you. Just wanted to make sure.